# How to remove blank lines from a text file in R?

Tags: json, r

I need to read some json files with many lines.

In some of the files I saw an empty line which causes an error when I try to read the file into R (using jsonlite).

How can I remove any blank lines using R?

Here is an example of the part with blank line:

```
mouse","trial_index":92,"time_elapsed":255348,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.0-27.0","subject":"693","answer":1},{"rt":-1,"stimulus":"/study_assets/creactive/static/images/bird.jpeg","key_press":-1,"block":"two-back","condition":"target","trial_type":"single-stim-mouse","trial_index":93,"time_elapsed":257160,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.0-28.0","subject":"693","answer":0},{"rt":407,"stimulus":"/study_assets/creactive/static/images/bird.jpeg","key_press":"mouse","block":"two-back","condition":"distractor","trial_type":"single-stim-mouse","trial_index":94,"time_elapsed":257871,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.0-29.0","subject":"693","answer":0}]

[{"rt":71,"key_press":"mouse","trial_type":"text","trial_index":0,"time_elapsed":74,"internal_node_id":"0.0-0.0","subject":"695"},{"rt":-1,"correct":false,"stimulus":"<DIV id=\"goNoGoFixationPoint\">+</DIV>","key_press":-1,"response":"fixation","trial_type":"categorize-mouse","trial_index":1,"time_elapsed":575,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.0-0.0","subject":"695"}
```

Comment: In `read.table()` one can set `blank.lines.skip=TRUE`

Comment: I get the following error when trying that: {Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 111 elements}

Comment: Your input is not a table! Please set `sep=...` (eventually `sep='µ'`) and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific how should I set sep value? I tried 'µ' without success.

Comment: What about `readLines(...)` ? After reading you have to delete the empty lines.

Comment: Question is, how can I automate the deletion of the empty lines?

Comment: After `x <- readLines(...)` they are empty strings in `x`. You can use `nchar()` or `grepl("^$", x)` or many other methods.

Comment: Thank you. So at the end I use readLines(x, skipNul= TRUE) to read the txt file into a variable. Then I use a small loop that runs every line. if(nchar(x[i]==0) I delete the line { x <- x[-i] }

Answer (score 1):

So at the end I use readLines and a loop with nchar() as follows:

```
x = JSONFILE
readLines(x, skipNul= TRUE) 
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
 if(nchar(x[i]==0) { 
 x <- x[-i] 
 }
}
```

Comment: 1. Where do you put the result of `readLines()` ? 2. Your for-loop is equivalent to `x <- x[nchar(x)!=0]` 3. BTW: For only one expression the curly braces are not needed.

Comment: I put it in data frame/file (dataframe <- readLines...). 2. I'm not familiar enough with the R syntax. I guess you suggestion is better. Thank you for your kind help.